# How to optimally visualise hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, visualization, hyperparameter-tuning

I am working on a basic Neural network and want to show performance of model with respect to different parameters.[image: Here is my dataframe looks like.]

I need help with suggestions for impactful visualizations. I can not make countourplots as far as I understand because for that I have to define loss as a function of the parameters. Please suggest some interesting plots.

Comment: Simple visualisations can be effective, so I suggest plotting the parameter of interest against the performance using a line plot or bar chart.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a "Parallel Coordinates" plot, in which

- A model is represented by a line
- Model performance is highlighted in colour
- Model hyper-parameters are presented in axes along with their respective values.

I attach below an example which you can generate either using Tensorboard or tools like Weights & Biases.

You can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams) and [here](https://docs.wandb.ai/ref/app/features/panels/parallel-coordinates) resources on how to implement this representation for each of the tools above, respectively.

Hope this helps, good luck!

[image]